# MongoDb Document Not creating discordjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, discord.js

I have this code

```
const usermarket = require('./usermarkets')

const data2 = usermarket.findOne({User:message.author.id})
if(!data2) {
    let StonkMarket = new usermarket({
      User:message.author.id,
      bobloxowned:0,
      fattyowned:0,
      yeetowned:0,
      crunchyrollowned:0,
      generatorowned:0,
      })
 StonkMarket.save().catch(err => console.log(err))
return message.reply('created')
}
```

But it doesn't create a document in the collection. Here is the usermarket schema code

```
const userMarket = mongoose.Schema({
    User:String,
    bobloxowned:Number,
    fattyowned:Number,
    yeetowned:Number,
    crunchyrollowned:Number,
    generatorowned:Number,
    

})

module.exports = mongoose.model("StonkMarketUser", userMarket, 'usermarkets')
```

It was supposed to create a document with all the things, but instead it did nothing.

Comment: You are only fetching a document but never pushing

Comment: You can try [`finOneAndUpdate()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html)

Comment: `findOne` and `save` are asynchronous, are they `await`ed somewhere?

Comment: @Joe thank you so much I forgot to add await usermarket